# how to search between multi property of a vertex in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

I have to find vehicle between time 8.00 & 9.00 with respect to vertex label 'A'

I have following output
`[10.00,8.30,v1,v2]`

I have tried the following query and get the result above

```
g.V().
  hasLabel('A').
  has('time',between(8.00,9.00)).as('z').
  repeat(out().simplePath()).
    until(hasLabel('H')).
  path().
  select('z').
    by(values('vehicle','time').
  fold())
```

expected result 
`[8.30,v2]`
also help me to find path between A,C,D,E,G,H .
 I tired the following code

```
g.V().hasLabel('a').repeat(out().simplePath()).until(hasLabel('h')).
     path().by(values('vehicle','time').fold())
```

my received output

```
[[10.00,8.30,v1,v2],[10.30,9.00,9.30,v1,v2,v3],[11.00,9.30,10.00,v1,v2,v3],[1
1.30,10.00,10.30,v1,v2,v3],[12.00,11.00,v1,v3],[12.30,11.30,v1,v3]]
```

expected output

```
[a:[10.00,v1],c:[11.00,v1],d:[11.30,v1],e:[12.00,v1],g:[12.30,v1],h[1.00,v1]]
[a:[8.30,v2],c:[9.00,v2],d:[9.30,v2],e:[10.00,v2],g:[11.00,v3],h:[11.30,v3]]
```

[A sample graph is provided below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WorWJ.png)

Comment: It is much easier to help with questions like this one if you can provide a small sample graph that allows the query in your question to be run to help with reproduction of the results you are seeing. Here is an example of a way to build a small sample graph: https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/blob/master/sample-code/quick-btree.groovy

Comment: What is 'd' meant to be in your query? There is no 'd' property in the data you added.

Comment: 'd' meant vehicle,'e' meant time excepted result  [time,vehicle]

Comment: In the data you shared there is no vertex with a label 'a' and a time between 1 and 2 so the query does nothing. It would help if you could edit the question to remove things like 'e' and between(1,2) and include the actual query that generated the results you shared initially.

Comment: 'v1' is the vertex with label 'a' as mentioned in query

Comment: Ok. So as I said there is no time between 1,2 for V1 so the query you shared will not return any results.

Comment: I think the reason this is proving hard is due to your data model. This would be a really simple query if instead of keeping everything in lists you used edges instead. That is also a much more 'graph' centric way to model this. How about changing the model so that you have a vertex A with edges to each vehicle and each vertex has a vehicle ID and a time. With that data model these queries will be incredibly simple to express. As a general rule, if the queries are proving really hard to write - ask the question can my data model change in a way that will make the queries easier to write.